# I want to convert a powershell output into a html file

Tags: html, powershell

I wanted to convert a powershell result to html file,

I have an array $f="gsds,jv,hfvw".

I want the html file to print each element of the array in a new line.

How to do it?

Thanks!

I used this code
$f="6e47812,662348,8753478"
Get-Service |ConvertTo-Html -Body "

$f

"|out-file D:\service.html

And the out put was

6e47812,662348,8753478

Comment: `$f` is not an array. It is a string. What is its significance to services for you? `Get-Service |ConvertTo-Html` would be enough to create html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? :

```
$test = "abc","def","ghi"
foreach ($row in $test) {Write-Output "<p> $row </p>"}
```

Output :

```
<p> abc </p>
<p> def </p>
<p> ghi </p>
```

Comment: yeah,but it should be in html.. I have found a way tho

Comment: I stored the array as $f="gsds,</br>,jvh,</br>,fvw".

Answer (score 0):

cls
$Path = 'C:\temp\test' #Path Directory

Grab a recursive list of all subfolders

```
$SubFolders = dir $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName}
```

Iterate through the list of subfolders and grab the first file in each

```
ForEach ($Folder in $SubFolders)
    {
    $FullFileName = dir $Folder | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

For every file grab it's location and output the robocopy command ready for use

```
ForEach ($File in $FullFileName)
    {
    $FilePath = $File.DirectoryName
    $FileName = $File.Name
    write-output "$FilePath $FileName"  
    }

}
```

Comment: getting output
C:\temp\test\Folder1 02test.txt
C:\temp\test\Folder2 New Microsoft PowerPoint.txt
C:\temp\test\Folder3 Sumee.docx
PS C:\temp\Test>

need output in html